# Problem with requesting data from MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and a table that stores the local IP addresses and information for authorization. I try to get the IP of all servers, but I only get the first one. And I don’t know how to fix it, is it even possible?

PHPMyAdmin :

[image]

Code :

[image]

Comment: You only selected `id=0`. Why would you expect to get other servers?

Comment: BTW, there's no need for the inner loop. You're only selecting one column, so just put `$row['host']` in the `<option>`

Comment: Servers have id, i am trying to select by id, 192.168.1.228 - id 0, 192.168.1.229 - id 0.

Comment: I am receiving next array : Array -> [host] 192.168.1.228, [0] 192.168.1.228

Comment: `192.168.1.229 = id 1`

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns both numeric and named indexes, so it returns every column twice.

Comment: Barmar, changed id after screenshot, not helped.

Comment: so, may be, error in table? or it's something wrong with code?

Comment: What did you change the id to? As long as you have `WHERE id = something` it will only return one host.

Comment: If you want them all, use `SELECT host FROM baseip` with no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please post your code as plain text so we can copy and paste. Indent it 4 spaces with the `{}` tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all hosts, don't use a `WHERE` clause that restricts to certain IDs.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT host FROM baseip");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option>" . $row['host'] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php:128 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php(128): mysqli_fetch_assoc(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 128

Comment: It was a typo `baseiip`